# Django ValueError "Cannot query "asd": Must be "OnlineGame" instance."

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I got this error; "Cannot query "asd": Must be "OnlineGame" instance."

(asd is gameslug) (OnlineGame is class which store online game name like; lol pubg)

models.py

```
class Game(models.Model):
      match=models.ManyToManyField(Match,related_name="gamematch")

class Match(models.Model):
      teams = models.ManyToManyField(Team, through='MatchTeam')

class MatchTeam(models.Model):
    match = models.ForeignKey('Match', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    team = models.ForeignKey(Team, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    rank = models.IntegerField(default=20)
    point=models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

views.py

```
    game=get_object_or_404(Game
            ,tournament__slug=tournamentslug
            ,slug=slug,game__slug=gameslug)

    teams = MatchTeam.objects.filter(
    match__game=game
).annotate(
    points=F('rank')
).order_by(
    '-broyale_match', 'rank'
)
```

Comment: what is `game__slug` doing here? That relation seems not defined in your shared views? It looks like this expects an `OnlineGame`, not a slug.

Comment: if i delete teams part it works

Comment: i changed match__game to match__game__tournament__slug=tournamentslug, it works. However, why  match__game doesn't work idk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I replaced match__game to match__game__tournament__slug=tournamentslug and then it works